# How to play security cam records

Tags: windows, media, media-player

I have a security video records on my computer. And try to play them, I almost tried all possible alternative players. The file extensions are exp and h264, some errors I have received could not render file or shn error..

Could you please suggest a possible solution?

Comment: you might want to mention explicitly what players you've tried and which version of windows, and running something like [gspot](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/) to get information on what exactly the codec is.

Comment: What players have you tried?

Comment: What were they recorded with?

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend trying [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/).

> VLC is a free and open source cross-platform multimedia player and framework that plays most multimedia files as well as DVD, Audio CD, VCD, and various streaming protocols.